# WPF Converters for radio buttons not working

Tags: wpf, binding, radio-button, converters

I have two radiobuttons which are bound to the same property .There are 2 converters for the radio buttons. But the conversion for the 2 nd checkbox only happens the 1st time . Is there something wrong in the code.

```
<RadioButton Margin="5,1" GroupName="groupValueOrTime" Name="radioButtonTimeDriven" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Path=TriggerType ,Converter={StaticResource dailyTriggerConverter}}"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" >Time Driven</RadioButton>
<RadioButton Margin="5,1" GroupName="groupValueOrTime" Name="radioButtonValueDriven" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=TriggerType,Converter={StaticResource valueDrivenTriggerConverter}}" >Value Driven</RadioButton>
```

Code:

```
public class TriggerTypeDailyToBoolProperty:IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
       //convert from TriggerType to bool:
        int TriggerType=int.Parse(value.ToString());
        if (TriggerType == 0 || TriggerType == 1 || TriggerType == 2 || TriggerType == 3 || TriggerType == 4 || TriggerType == 5 || TriggerType == 6)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool isChecked = (bool)value;
        return (isChecked? 0: -1);
    }

    #endregion
}

public class TriggerTypeValueDrivenToBoolProperty : IValueConverter
{
   #region IValueConverter Members

   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       //convert from TriggerType to bool:
       int TriggerType = int.Parse(value.ToString());
       if (TriggerType == 9)
           return true;
       else
           return false;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       bool isChecked = (bool)value;
       return (isChecked ? 9 : -1);
   }

   #endregion
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me how you want this to work but I tried your code and it seems to run fine so the problem may be something else. Are you implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and do you raise `PropertyChanged` when you update `TriggerType`? On a side note, you might want to consider changing the 7 comparisons in the first Converter to something like `if (TriggerType >= 0 && TriggerType <= 6)`

Comment: k ...lets say i have 3 trigger buttons each with TriggerType value as 0,1 and 9. The 1st time i click on all 3 buttons, the radio buttons are checked correctly. when i click again on the 1st btn it calls the 1st converter but doesnt check for the 2nd converter. so when i click on the last btn both the radio buttons stay unchecked. (Thanks for correcting the code btw)

Answer (score 1):

I think you will require to have two different boolean properties in your view model.

Please refer below example depicting viewmodel.

```
public class TriggerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _triggerTypeValue;
    private bool _triggerTypeTime;
    public bool TriggerTypeValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _triggerTypeValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _triggerTypeValue = value;
            OnPropertychanged("TriggerTypeValue");
            SetTriggerTypeTime(!_triggerTypeValue);
        }
    }

    public bool TriggerTypeTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _triggerTypeTime;
        }
        set
        {
            _triggerTypeTime = value;
            OnPropertychanged("TriggerTypeTime");
            SetTriggerTypeValue(!_triggerTypeTime);
        }
    }

    public TriggerViewModel()
    {
        _triggerTypeValue = false;
        _triggerTypeTime = true;
    }

    private void SetTriggerTypeTime(bool value)
    {
        _triggerTypeTime = value;
        OnPropertychanged("TriggerTypeTime");
    }

    private void SetTriggerTypeValue(bool value)
    {
        _triggerTypeValue = value;
        OnPropertychanged("TriggerTypeValue");
    }

    private void OnPropertychanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged!= null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

For XAML

```
<RadioButton Margin="5,1" GroupName="groupValueOrTime" Name="radioButtonTimeDriven" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Path=TriggerType}"  
             Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
     Time Driven 
</RadioButton>

<RadioButton Margin="5,1" GroupName="groupValueOrTime" Name="radioButtonValueDriven" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
             IsChecked="{Binding Path=TriggerType}">
      Value Driven
<RadioButton>
```

Note: This approach removes Converters and allow you to keep your business logic in central view model.

Answer (score 1):

Combining grouping, radio buttons, and binding doesn't work.  An odd feature of binding is that if you set the value of a bound target property in code, it disables the binding.  The assumption that the design of binding appears to be making is that the only ways you should change a target property is by using the UI or by changing the source property it's bound to, and if a piece of code explicitly sets the value of a bound target property, it knows what it's doing.

Unfortunately, this means that grouped radio buttons, which set each others' values in code when they're changed, break their bindings when the user clicks on them.  Oops.

The solution's simple:  bind the radio buttons to properties in your view model, eliminate the grouping, and put logic in the view model to handle the mutually-exclusive nature of the bound properties, e.g.:

```
private bool _Option1;

public bool Option1
{
   get { return _Option1; }
   set
   {
      if (value != _Option1)
      {
         _Option1 = value;
         if (value)
         {
            Option2 = false;
            Option3 = false;
         }
      }
      OnPropertyChanged("Option1");
   }
}
```